# How to assign values of structs with different name but exactly same element and type (C++11)？

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, variable-assignment, class-members

I got two structs. **Some parts of the two** structs have exactly the same element type (and name).

How can I assign one with another's value?

as below demonstrated:

```cpp
struct X
{
    struct {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
    } z;
    int c = 0;
};

struct Y
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
};

int main()
{
    X x{ 1,2,3 };
    Y y;
    // I know i can do:
    y.a = x.z.a;
    y.b = x.z.b;

    // Is there a simple way like:
    // y = x.z;
}
```

I looked into `memcpy` but in my real case, the `X` is much more complicated and dynamic in length. `memcpy` looks not quite help for me.

Comment: the only common type is `int`. `z` is not the same type as `Y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple way like:
> y = x.z;
> ?

`Y` is not same as `decltype(X::z)`. Therefore, it is not possible without any further tweaks.

One way is, to provide [copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) overload for `Y`, which can accept the [`decltype(X::z)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) type, and does the assignment to `Y`.

```
struct Y
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    using Z_t = decltype(X::z);
    Y& operator=(const Z_t& z)
    {
        a = z.a;
        b = z.b;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Now you can write

```
X x{ 1,2,3 };
Y y;

y = x.z;
```

[See a live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/e7o64Goqb)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you could rewrite your code to read:

```cpp
struct Y
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
};

struct X
{
    Y z;
    int c = 0;
};
```

Now it *is* the same struct.

Comment: thanks, pity both struct X/Y are out of my control, them are defined by different guys in my team. i think i will ask the guys include assignment operator overload as JeJO's sugguestion, if indeed there is no direct tricks like `y = x.z`

Comment: I feared this might be but I did not want to pass on the most simple solution. Note that writing an assignment op will only be possible if `Y` is known where `X` is defined or vice versa. If not, you will have to bite the bullet and write the conversion yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The two are not of same type. Maybe you actually want them to be the same type, then the "simple" way to be able to write `y = x.z;` is this:

```
struct X {
    struct {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
    } z;
    int c = 0;
};


int main() {
    X x{ 1,2,3 };
    auto y = x.z;
}
```

or

```
decltype(x.z) y;
y = x.z;
```